# Existence of a curve on a submanifold.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, submanifold

We have the following homework assignment, which result should be used for three other exercises. Unfortunately I didn't come up with the right idea. Maybe someone can help with hints, then I would elaborate within the forum. Thank you in advance! So here is the exercise:

Let $a$ be a regular value of $g$ and $M = g^{-1}(\{a\}) \neq \emptyset$ a $n-1$ dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $p \in M$ and $v \in T_pM$. Prove, that there exists a curve $\alpha: [-\epsilon, \epsilon] \rightarrow M$, such that $\alpha(0) = p$ and $\alpha'(0)=v$.

Comment: What is your definition of the tangent space? It's often defined as a equivalence class of curves through a point satisfying the conditions you gave, which is proved in any reasonable text to be equivalent to the definitions via derivations or quotients of ideals. As long as your manifold is nontrivial it has a nontrivial tangent space at each point and thus such a curve exists. You don't need anything about regular values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outline (maybe not the easiest approach). You want a hint, so I let you fill in the details.
Wlog let $a=0$

There is a curve $\gamma:(-\tau, \tau)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\gamma(0)= p$ and $\gamma^\prime(0)= v$. (You may take $\gamma(t) = p + tv$)

The problem is now, that the image of $\gamma$ may not be a subset of $M$. However, $g(\gamma(0))= g(p) = 0$ since $p\in M$.

Let $n := \frac{\nabla g}{||\nabla g||}$ and $\sigma(t,s) = \gamma(t) + sn(p)$. Consider the map $\xi:(s,t)\mapsto g(\sigma(t,s))$. It satisfies $\xi(0,0)=0 $ and

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\xi |_{t,s=0}=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}g\circ \sigma |_{t,s=0}= dg(p)n(p)\neq 0$$

So the implicit function theorem implies that there is a (locally unique) map $s= h(t)$ such that $g(\sigma(t, h(t)))=0$

The curve you are after is $\sigma(t,h(t))$.

(**Note:** if you are not familiar with the topic this may look a bit like magic. It is not. You must know that $n$ is the unit normal to $M$ - what is happening here is that with $\sigma$ we disturb the curve $\gamma$ in direction towards $M$, so that we get a curve in $M$)